# xcode: ios8, rotate on single view of the app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have an app that I have set to only run on portrait mode only.

But I have a page view where I am showing a photo but wants to enable it to auto rotate with the device.  I tried to put these codes but its not working

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

Can someone please advise what's needed to do now?

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the point of rotation on your imageview

```
UIImageView *yourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
yourImageView.center = CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0);
yourImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
```

Comment: but this is a force rotation right? What i need is when user rotates the phone, the photo will follow to rotate